Replace single backslash with double backslash so that json becomes parseable
I am using cURL inside bash to fetch json data from remote API. Also using jq to parse and loop through the json array to perform additional operations. The response looks like this:
[
     {
        "services": [
            "HOM"
        ],
        "specialServiceId": "APPOINTMENT",
        "brandedName": "Appointment Home Delivery®",
        "incompatibleSpecialServices": [
            "DATE",
            "EVENING"
        ],
        "inputParameterRules": [
            {
                "name": "PHONE_NUMBER",
                "brandedName": "Appointment Phone Number",
                "required": true,
                "format":"^\d{10,15}$",
                "description": "A valid 10 to 15 digit phone number including area code and optional extension"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "services": [
            "NDA_AM_EH",
            "2DA"
        ],
        "specialServiceId": "NO_SIG",
        "brandedName": "No Signature Required",
        "categoryId": "DEL_CON",
        "incompatibleSpecialServices": [
            "SIG",
            "DIRECT_SIG"
        ],
        "inputParameterRules": [
            {
                "name": "SIGNATURE_RELEASE_NUMBER",
                "description": "A valid signature release number"
            }
        ],
        "specialServiceLevel": "ALLPKG"
    },
  {...},
  {...}
] 

As you can see the format field inside inputParameterRules for PHONE_NUMBER contains a single backslash which makes this JSON un-parseable.
I would like to

Either replace the single backslash with a double backslash before storing this json in a file OR
Delete the format field.

Tried something like this:
 SPECIAL_SERVICES_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}" "${SPECIAL_SERVICES_URL}" | jq '[.[].inputParameterRules[] | del(.format)]')

But it produces no results.
Thanks

I think you're saying that the remote API is delivering invalid JSON.  The best solution would be to get the API to deliver valid JSON in the first place, and presumably, that's something the API provider would care about.

Alternatively, if you have influence over the form of the data, then you could consider working around the problem be modifying the format regex from ^\d{10,15}$ to ^[0-9]{10,15}$, or possibly, depending on the target regex engine and desired behavior, to ^[[:digit:]]{10,15}$.

The format is a regex and apparently a valid one. So, the remote team is not willing to make the change on their side. Therefore, I am trying option like jq sed etc to manipulate the reponse.

It doesn't matter at all what the nature of the data is, or whether it is valid in the API provider's database.  The API promises (I take it) to deliver valid JSON responses, and it is delivering invalid JSON instead.  This can and should be fixed on their side.  A client-side workaround is possible, but you should not accept the provider returning malformed responses.

I see some extra commas in that that also make it invalid json. Agree with John; whoever's in charge of the code that generates this data needs to fix their problems.

Are you sure this is exactly what the API produces, and hasn't been mangled by something like an echo command that tries to parse backslash escapes? Passing around data like this in shell scripts without subtly mangling it can be surprisingly difficult.

@Shawn I had shortened the response manually. Fixed it now.

echo '\d{10,15}' | jq -R '{format: .}' outputs {"format": "\\d{10,15}"}. The remote team owes you an explanation why they think they are correct.

As I mentioned in comments, the best approach would be to fix the API (or get its provider to fix it) so that it delivers well-formed JSON.  There is every reason to demand this, for an API that promises JSON responses is buggy if it delivers invalid JSON under any circumstances.
Alternatively, if you can control the data, then the best workaround would be to reformulate the regex in the API's database to an equivalent one that does not use backslash (\) characters.  This should get you API responses that do not require client-side correction.
If neither of those is viable, then the best long-term approach would be to dump your unreasonable API provider in favor of a better one, but in the short term, there are client-side workarounds.

I would like to

Either replace the single backslash with a double backslash before storing this json in a file OR
Delete the format field.

Tried something like this:
SPECIAL_SERVICES_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}" "${SPECIAL_SERVICES_URL}" | jq '[.[].inputParameterRules[] | del(.format)]')


Since the problem to be solved is that the file is not valid JSON, it stands to reason that you cannot solve it via a mechanism that involves parsing the file as JSON.
You can filter it with sed.  The issue here is distinguishing between data that need fixed and data that don't, especially if there is hope that the API provider will evantually fix the issue on their side.
Here are some alternatives you could consider:

This sed command will dumbly double every backslash in the input:
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'

This will fix the specific malformation presented in the question, but it will break any JSON-ly correct backslash usage elsewhere in the file.  And if the API provider ever gets their stuff together, it will start breaking the correct JSON they then emit.

This one is a bit more targeted.  It will double every backslash in any line that matches /"format":/
sed '/"format":/ s/\\/\\\\/g'

The targeting reduces the likelihood that erstwhile valid data elsewhere in the file are corrupted, but also avoids fixing such data if they are in fact invalid.

This one will add one backslash at the end of any run of an odd number of backslashes that is bounded by non-backslash characters:
sed -E 's/([^\\](\\\\)*)\\([^\\])/\1\\\\\3/g'

That will fix your current malformation and not break when the API provider fixes your particular issue, but it might break JSON-ly correct backslash usage elsewhere.

Of course, you can combine the last two:
sed -E '/"format":/ s/([^\\](\\\\)*)\\([^\\])/\1\\\\\3/g'

That gives you a fairly narrowly targeted approach that will not necessarily break when the API provider fixes the issue.


The overarching theme here is that if you can't rely on the API provider to emit correct data in the first place, then the best you can do is heuristically correct whatever they do emit, and that path is strewn with traps and pitfalls.  You have to be concerned both about "fixing" data that were correct and valid in the first place and about failing to recognize or fix incorrect data.

It turns out that halaxa's "JSON Machine" (https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine)
is very lenient in accepting "strings"
when reading JSON, so one JSON-aware approach would be to use JSON Machine.
For simplicity, the following uses the "jm" script (https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm)
that uses JSON Machine under the hood.
Since your post indicates you're particularly interested in the "inputParameterRules",
I'll focus on that in the following.
In brief, the following line produces the output (valid JSON) shown below:
jm  --pointer /-/inputParameterRules input.pseudojson 

Output:
{"name":"PHONE_NUMBER","brandedName":"Appointment Phone Number","required":true,"format":"^d{10,15}$","description":"A valid 10 to 15 digit phone number including area code and optional extension"}
{"name":"SIGNATURE_RELEASE_NUMBER","description":"A valid signature release number"}

Since this is a stream of valid JSON objects, you can now use jq.
